# What is the reason of kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ssl, certificate

I'd like to validate my ssl server certificates with some extra checks. And sometimes I get a

```
kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure
```

instead of

`kSecTrustResultProceed` or `kSecTrustResultUnspecified`

It seems to happen if

- the certificate is md5 hashed (IOS5)
- the server does not present the root and intermediate certificates
- the `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly(trust,YES)` 
  is set and the anchor certificate is only in the built in anchor certificates
- the certificate is expired
- ?

It depends on the AppleX509TP policy used to evaluate the trust.

My problem is I do not want to trust if the chain fails, but I want to trust if MD5 is used.

Is there a way to find out why the evaluation failed?

As an alternative is there a way to extract the `CSSM_ALGID_MD5` from a `SecCertificateRef`?

Answer (score 3):

It may be a server certificate problem....

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551643/unable-to-trust-a-self-signed-certificate-on-iphone), I solved my **kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure** problem, adding `subjectAltName = DNS:example.com` into openssl config file, specifically in server key generation...

If you are not using openssl to generate it, I'm sorry but I can help you.. Anyway if you want to use openssl, [here](http://linuxconfig.org/apache-web-server-ssl-authentication) is a good tutorial to generate those keys and sign then with your own root certificate authority.

From this tutorial, I just changed my openssl server config file to:

```
    [ server ]
    basicConstraints = critical,CA:FALSE
    keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
    extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
    nsCertType = server
    subjectAltName = IP:10.0.1.5,DNS:office.totendev.com
```

Hope it helps !

**EDITED:**

My Server evaluation code:

```
#pragma mark - SERVER Auth Helper
//Validate server certificate with challenge
+ (BOOL)validateServerWithChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
//Get server trust management object a set anchor objects to validate it
SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates([challenge.protectionSpace serverTrust], (__bridge CFArrayRef)[self allowedCAcertificates]);
//Set to server trust management object to JUST ALLOW those anchor objects assigned to it (ABOVE), and disable apple CA trusts 
SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly([challenge.protectionSpace serverTrust], YES);
//Try to evalute it
SecTrustResultType evaluateResult = kSecTrustResultInvalid; //evaluate result
OSStatus sanityCheck = SecTrustEvaluate([challenge.protectionSpace serverTrust], &evaluateResult);
//Check for no evaluate error
if (sanityCheck == noErr) {
    //Check for result
    if ([[self class] validateTrustResult:evaluateResult]) { return YES ; }
}
//deny!
return NO ;
}
//Validate SecTrustResulType
+ (BOOL)validateTrustResult:(SecTrustResultType)result {
switch (result) {
    case kSecTrustResultProceed: { TDLog(kLogLevelHandshake,nil,@"kSecTrustResultProceed"); return YES ; }
        break;
    case kSecTrustResultConfirm: { TDLog(kLogLevelHandshake,nil,@"kSecTrustResultConfirm"); return YES ; }
        break;
    case kSecTrustResultUnspecified: { TDLog(kLogLevelHandshake,nil,@"kSecTrustResultUnspecified"); return YES ; }
        break;
    case kSecTrustResultDeny: { TDLog(kLogLevelHandshake,nil,@"kSecTrustResultDeny"); return YES ; }
        break;
    case kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure: { TDLog(kLogLevelHandshake,nil,@"kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure"); return NO ; }
        break;
    case kSecTrustResultInvalid: { TDLog(kLogLevelHandshake,nil,@"kSecTrustResultInvalid"); return NO ; }
        break;
    case kSecTrustResultOtherError: { TDLog(kLogLevelHandshake,nil,@"kSecTrustResultOtherError"); return NO ; }
        break;
    case kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure: { TDLog(kLogLevelHandshake,nil,@"kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure"); return NO ; }
        break;
    default: { TDLog(kLogLevelHandshake,nil,@"unkown certificate evaluate result type! denying..."); return NO ; }
        break;
}

}
```

Hope now it helps :) !

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But my problem is I don't issue the certificates myself.

Comment: So your problem is your CA certificate or in your evaluation! How are you importing your key ? From each source , is a File ? Edited in my comment is my evaluation code...

Comment: Hi. Thanks for updating. My problem is how do I get the cause of a kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure because somtimes I want to return YES.

Comment: Hm.... you probably will need to go deeper ! Have you tried to make your own expiration validation as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340937/continuously-getting-ksectrustresultrecoverabletrustfailure-while-trust-evaluati ??

Comment: Probably If I want to know the cause of my 'kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure' I'll make each validation for my own, so I can know where it's failure. Hard work just to know what is causing and may accept it.It would be better to just accept good certificates...

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to find out why the evaluation failed?

Call `SecTrustCopyProperties()` after calling `SecTrustEvaluate()`:

```
SecTrustRef trust = ...;
SecTrustResultType trustResult = kSecTrustResultOtherError;
OSStatus status = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);
if (trustResult == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure) {
    NSArray * trustProperties = (__bridge_transfer id)
        SecTrustCopyProperties(certTrust);
}
```

`trustProperties` is an array of dictionaries, one dictionary per cert in the cert chain evaluated. Every dictionary has an entry `title`, containing the name of the cert and if the cert didn't evaluate, it also contains an entry `error` containing the error. E.g. if the problem was that the cert has expired, the value of `error` will be `CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED`.